# How will I populate value in textarea and radio buttons

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have fetch data from database in $tableRe. Now I have to print values in textarea and also have to check the radio button.

Here is my code,

```
$sql = "select (address, gender) from stud table";
if($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $tableRe[]=$row;
    }
}

<form>
Address : <br>
   <textarea value="<?php echo $tableRe[0]['address']; ?>"></textarea><br>
Gender : <br>
  <input type="radio" value="Male">Male
  <input type="radio" value="Female">Female <br>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Please help me regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **SO != Free coding resource** We will willingly help if what **you** write does not work, **but we dont work from specs** or ___Please check my code let me know how will it possible___

Comment: I will keep remind this next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply condition on `checked` HTML attribute.

Try this:

```
<form>
   Address : <br>
   <textarea><?php echo $tableRe[0]['address']; ?></textarea> <br/>
   Gender : <br>
   <input type="radio" value="Male" <?php echo $tableRe[0]['gender'] == 'Male' ? 'checked' : '';  ?> >Male
   <input type="radio" value="Female" <?php echo $tableRe[0]['gender'] == 'Female' ? 'checked' : '';  ?>>Female <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks It worked. Can I do same thing for select values ?

Comment: Yeah, you just need to mention `selected` instead of `checked`

Comment: @ObjectManipulator Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Value has to be placed between the openning and closing tags :

```
<texterea name="whatever">Textarea value goes here</textarea>
```

To set a radio/checkbox as selected/checked, you need to add to it a "checkded" attribute :

```
<!-- HTML4 -->
<input type="radio" name="whatever" value="value1" checked="checked" /> Label 1
<input type="radio" name="whatever" value="value2" /> Label 2
<input type="radio" name="whatever" value="value3" /> Label 3

<!-- HTML5 -->
<input type="radio" name="whatever" value="value1" checked /> Label 1
<input type="radio" name="whatever" value="value2" /> Label 2
<input type="radio" name="whatever" value="value3" /> Label 3
```